# Find strings in a file with certain beginning and ending and replace with another string using command

Tags: regex, sed

I want to replace all the expression with pattern `abc + something )))` to `cba)` in a file. The something in the first expression is different in all the instances. 
For example: change `abc, ifojg)))` to `cba)`;  or change `abc "asdf")))` to `cba)`.
I've tried:

```
sed -i 's/abc*)))/new/g' file
```

But it did nothing on the file. How should I modify the code? I am not familiar with the regular expression. Please explain every symbol in the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo 'abc, ifojg)))' | sed -r 's/abc[^\)]+\)\)\)/cba)/'
```

The pattern is `abc` followed by characters other than `)` , followed by `)))`

Comment: Thanks. If I don't need the condition of `[^\)]`, what should I put there? I notice that deleting this part directly does not work

Comment: note that `\)` inside character class will match both ``\`` and `)` characters, in other words, `[^)]` should be used to indicate characters other than `)`